# Symfony request not returning Date header

Tags: symfony, http-headers, request

I'm working on an API and I can't get Sf2 to catch the "Date" parameter from the request header... Demo is below. I'm testing my API via Postman.

```
$date = $this->request->headers->get('Date');
$auth = $this->request->headers->get('Authorization');

echo $date; // NULL
echo $auth; // whatever i pased.
```

[image: Date header demo]

A very strange behaviour indeed ! Could anyone know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` header is a restricted one and it's not possible to overwrite it unless you use the Interceptor Chrome Extension (see [this](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) official link for details).

This is a list of restricted headers:

- Accept-Charset
- Accept-Encoding
- Access-Control-Request-Headers
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Connection
- Content-Length
- Cookie
- Content-Transfer-Encoding
- Date
- Expect
- Host
- Keep-Alive
- Origin
- Referer
- TE
- Trailer
- Transfer-Encoding
- Upgrade
- User-Agent
- Via

That's why you're getting an empty header.

Answer (score -1):

change

```
$date = $this->request->headers->get('Date');
```

to

```
$date = $this->request->headers->get('X-Date');
```

Comment: Evg thks for the effort, but i know any other params works. I want to understand why the Date param doesn't ! (x-Date for for demonstrating)